# Getting 400 error while hitting api to get access token for java box sdk using Jwt

Tags: jwt, access-token, box

I'm using Box-Java-Sdk. The authentication method that I'm using to get the access token is OAuth2 with Jwt. While hitting the api for getting access token for the very first time when i start the server, I'm getting error code 400. The error only comes for the first time and then the code starts to execute properly without any error. following is the error snippet:

```
com.box.sdk.BoxAPIException: The API returned an error code: 400
    at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIResponse.<init>(BoxAPIResponse.java:70)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxJSONResponse.<init>(BoxJSONResponse.java:30)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIRequest.trySend(BoxAPIRequest.java:435)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIRequest.send(BoxAPIRequest.java:221)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIRequest.send(BoxAPIRequest.java:196)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.authenticate(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:308)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.tryRestoreUsingAccessTokenCache(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:368)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppEnterpriseConnection(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:179)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppEnterpriseConnection(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:206)
    at com.hubble.hubbleEngine.policyTypes.OAuth.getEnterpriseToken(OAuth.java:737)
    at com.hubble.saas.api.SaaSAPI.setTokens(SaaSAPI.java:255)
    at com.hubble.saas.api.SaaSAPI.setTokenIfExpired(SaaSAPI.java:233)
    at com.hubble.newuilayer.daoimpl.ReportsSummaryDaoImp.getApiReportsSummaryDaoList(ReportsSummaryDaoImp.java:392)
    at com.hubble.newuilayer.impls.auditcontrol.ApiReportPageImpl.forwardToJSP(ApiReportPageImpl.java:54)
    at com.hubble.newuilayer.servlets.MainServlet.processRequest(MainServlet.java:147)
    at com.hubble.newuilayer.servlets.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.hubble.newuilayer.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:33)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.hubble.uilayer.servlets.RedirectionFilter.doFilter(RedirectionFilter.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.hubble.newuilayer.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

While reading various answers from web, i thought that it was an error off refresh token but I'm not using refresh token since I don't get the refresh token instead I get the token expiration time.

Th error also comes while getting the access token for individual user, this happens when I stop the sever within few minutes, and restart it again since in this case the access token remains valid(I save it in database) and now when i try getting the access token for very first user the same error comes and then the access token for other user comes properly.

Comment: Is it possible to share the code where you're getting this exception?

Comment: The exception was due to the "exp" in claim. I got a solution to it [link](https://community.box.com/t5/Box-Developer-Forum/Current-date-time-MUST-be-before-the-expiration-date-time-listed/td-p/17871) but I'm wondering if it's okay to change timezone this way. Thanks!